# Is someone trying to get my account banned by botting upvotes?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I have noticed that I get about 8-10 upvotes on my various questions and answers tagged [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda), every day for I think more than a week now. Even including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620578/auto-implicit-not-solved-even-though-it-should-be-straightforward-function-appl) misguided question that was basically just me mixing up Agda and Idris in my head.

Is this going to end up with my account getting banned because of botting/sockpuppeting?

Comment: Unlikely. Serial voting is just going to be reversed by the script. If somebody persists in doing it, I'd expect the mods to take it to that person, not to you. Unless there is evidence that *you* are upvoting these but if you're asking here, I'd hazard a guess there is no evidence of that.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah I made sure to get rid of all evidence /s

Comment: Unless their plan is to depress you with vote reversal history entries, the plan is too dumb to carry out. Usually those are users who found your contributions very helpful and go ahead and try to thank you by upvoting your other posts (most of the time in blissful ignorance that they are committing serial upvoting)

Comment: I also saw it several times that a user tries to thank someone by upvoting all of their questions, but this case is special: There are at least two account involved for voting (some questions upvoted twice), the votes of the two accounts are sometimes only seconds apart. Maybe flag one of your questions for moderator attention and explain the case, maybe you found a bot net trying to cover their tracks by voting also on people not involved? Moderators/CM can then investigate who else get upvotes from this accounts.

Comment: To compensate from the grief I'll downvote all your posts ....

Comment: Note: You don't need to also raise a flag about this series of serial upvoting. This question has already brought the situation to our attention. To specifically answer, even though the linked duplicate does answer you question: as long as there's no evidence that you are the one who is upvoting your account, or that you've otherwise participated in the serial voting in some way other than being the target of the voting, then, no, your account won't be suspended.