# "Serial voting reversed" destroyed my rep

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, serial-voting

I've been steadily gaining rep for several years answering questions on Stack Overflow (mostly ones with the [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) tag) and a few weeks ago I started seeing a lot of new upvotes on my old answers (one upvote per answer, all with the [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) tag). I assumed that someone was looking through all the questions tagged [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) and upvoting answers that they liked and since I have 116 answers while in total there are only 720 questions, it made sense that I was constantly getting new upvotes. I think others with answers in the [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) tag have gained rep too, but I don't know what the distribution is.

Then I saw this "Serial voting reversed" message and like -200 rep or something. I thought "easy come, easy go" and decided not to care. But today I got a whopping -3429 rep completely destroying everything I've gained in the past few years way beyond what I got from the recent "bull run". Here's how my reputation has been changing since 2018 and up until today:

[image]

Previously I was the top [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) answerer and now I'm only second with 1.63x less reputation than now-top answerer.

I have "top [agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agda) answerer on Stack Overflow" in my CV, I do care about the rep that I lost without any sensible reason. I've been contributing to this community for more than 7 years. Can this incident be investigated and my rep returned? Feel free to post any details publicly, apart from personal ones (like the IP address).

Comment: We handled a vote invalidation yesterday that we're already re-investigating - while I can't guarantee that you'll see all of the votes returned, I'm hoping that we'll be able to reinstate many of them. Please give us some time to investigate a bit more. Apologies for the confusion and the negative impact.

Comment: @Catija thanks! Will there be any post-mortem on what happened (regardless of the final outcome)?

Comment: We have to be cautious about that as it can be a bit too... public of how our system identifies and invalidates votes but I'll see if there's something we can talk about to explain what happened somewhat generally.

Comment: @Catija I'd be happy to sign an NDA and post either "I'm convinced" or "I'm not convinced" without going into any details whatsoever after seeing the data.

Comment: We look at patterns when we analyze cases of potential voting fraud. That can be a bit like reading tea leaves; it's not an exact science. In this case, someone with a bit less experience reading tea leaves handled it, and they didn't read the tea leaves in the same way that others with more experience probably would have. So, the team is following up on this, reviewing it again, and the results will probably change (some votes will be returned, but not all). This is about all we can say, NDA or not. You don't need to be convinced; this is already something being looked into.

Comment: Other comments from this post have been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234088/discussion-on-question-by-user3237465-serial-voting-reversed-destroyed-my-rep).

Comment: Interesting that you are seeing all these upvotes on your [agda] answers, as [I've been seeing the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408090/is-someone-trying-to-get-my-account-banned-by-botting-upvotes).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I’d like to apologize to anyone who experienced a temporary change in their reputation due to some votes that shouldn’t have been invalidated along with some that were clearly targeted. That was an error on my part, being a newer team member and not catching some nuances on two particular suspicious voting investigations that were submitted. It was my mistake, I take ownership of it, and I will strive to not make a similar error in the future.

As Catija mentioned, we can’t get into certain specifics because of privacy issues, but I would like to share that fraudulent voting tools for Community Managers (CMs) are not perfect. Public Platform and our team are aware and have written up documentation of what can be improved. We don’t have an ETA on what that will be on the roadmap but it is very much on our radar. With our current tools, it’s quite difficult to manually cancel some votes that come up in a query; it's an all-or-nothing thing for the most part. As CMs, we can’t reverse (reinstate) votes that we invalidated ourselves, which means that we can’t correct our own misclicks. We have to have a developer do it, which is why the reversal isn’t instantaneous. The hero of our story is [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/adam-lear), by the way, who, despite a busy week on his plate, made time to investigate and reverse the invalidations that needed to be done as quickly as possible.

Again, I’d like to apologize for any stress or confusion that was caused. We try our best not to make errors like this, but we’re human and mistakes can happen. When they do, we work really hard to fix them ASAP and take ownership of them so we don’t make the same mistakes in the future. The moderators were fantastic in alerting us right away, and, again, props to Adam for putting things right so speedily.

Comment: Thank you for all the work you put in to make things run smoothly! Even if it isn't said often enough, you and your work, along with the rest of the team likewise, are very much appreciated around here!!

Comment: In my opinion, letting us know who you are and that it was an oops earns you respect. (Also, just in case you ever get one, please remember that downvotes on meta are not personal: they are about an idea presented, but I guess the SE induction covers that nowadays.)

Comment: I can only agree with @zcoop98, thank you for your hard job. And honestly it sounds like situations like this are way more stressful for you than for users experiencing reputation fluctuations. And such situations are very much to be expected, they shouldn't cause you and the team to grind your teeth in anger trying to unroll things without having the right tools for that. From my perspective, there's not much difference between waiting a couple of days and a couple of weeks, but as a user I'd really appreciate a prompt automatic notice "we're reinvestigating".

Comment: Or perhaps you should just be given the ability to unroll changes, if at all possible. That would be easier on users and much easier on you as you wouldn't feel the pressure to rush anymore.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has been in this position more than once: this is an excellent response. It's all too tempting to walk away or shrug off mistakes, especially when correcting them involves a lot of time and effort - but faith in the system as a whole depends on doing so anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I've got most of the rep back and can confirm that everything lost was from the recent "bull run".

I'm keeping this answer, 'cause it has valuable comments. See the accepted answer for the full story.

Thank you folks for resolving this.

Comment: We can't go into details, but someone had deliberately upvoted several people (including you) and we caught them. The problem was [the system to undo those votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) caught far more votes than it should have (you weren't the only one affected and mods noted there was a problem after it was done). The second run caught a more appropriate set of votes that looked targeted (which is why you didn't regain all the lost rep).

Comment: @Machavity thank you! Do you have any idea why would anyone deliberately upvote a particular set of people? What's their incentive given that I don't remember paying anyone to do this? Just testing their software on guinea pigs? Why then make such obvious mistakes with upvotes happening within a minute? Just being curious.

Comment: That page doesn't just cover rapid upvotes. There's another case called invalidation (hinted at in the second paragraph) that can produce the same thing (see Rosie's post).  While I don't know why they did it, we have seen cases where someone discovers someone or something they like and they start an upvote spree. Usually the reversal script will catch it before it does serious harm, but the determined ones just slow the rate down to avoid that. It's possible that's what happened here since we didn't see any obvious vote trading (which is the common use case)